Python and OpenGL: Texture Not Filling Polygon Correctly in Koch Snowflake Rendering

Question:
I’m working on rendering a Koch snowflake with a sinus-plasma texture using PYTHON and OpenGL. The initial polygon is star-shaped, evolving into the Koch snowflake. My goal is to fill this polygon precisely with the texture while keeping its outline visible.
Problem:
The texture doesn’t fill the polygon correctly. Some points seem to be skipped, causing incorrect filling and visible gaps. The expected behavior is a smooth texture filling the entire polygon shape without errors.
What I’ve Tried:
Using GL_POLYGON for filling the shape.
Setting texture coordinates based on vertex positions.
Visualizing polygon points with red boxes to check the correct order.
import math
import random
import numpy as np
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *


def render_snowflake_with_plasma(snowflake, plasma_texture):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, plasma_texture)

    # paint texturized area
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    for point in snowflake:
        u = point[0] / 800
        v = point[1] / 600
        glTexCoord2f(u, v)
        glVertex2f(point[0] / 400 - 1, -(point[1] / 300 - 1))
    glEnd()

    # Draw outline of snowflake in constant color
    glLineWidth(3.0)
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)  # constant blue for outline
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP)
    for point in snowflake:
        glVertex2f(point[0] / 400 - 1, -(point[1] / 300 - 1))
    glEnd()

    # show polygon points separately
    for i, point in enumerate(snowflake):
        size = 6.0 + i * 5.0  # box size grows with index number
        glPointSize(size)
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)  # red color for boxes
        glBegin(GL_POINTS)
        glVertex2f(point[0] / 400 - 1, -(point[1] / 300 - 1))
        glEnd()

    pygame.display.flip()



def main():
   pygame.init()
   display = (800, 600)
   pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)
   gluOrtho2D(-1, 1, -1, 1)
   side_length = 260
   height = math.sqrt(3) / 2 * side_length
   base_triangle = [
       (400, 300 - (2 / 3) * height),
       (400 - side_length / 2, 300 + (1 / 3) * height),
       (400 + side_length / 2, 300 + (1 / 3) * height)
   ]
   plasma = create_sinus_plasma(800, 600, 0.2, 0.4, 1.5)
   plasma_texture = glGenTextures(1)
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, plasma_texture)
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 800, 600, 0, GL_RGB,   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, plasma)
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
   clock = pygame.time.Clock()
   rotation_angle = 0
   while True:
       for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type == QUIT:
               pygame.quit()
               return
       iteration_depth = 1
       iteration_modes = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
       snowflake = koch_snowflake(base_triangle, iteration_depth, iteration_modes)
       print("Raw Snowflake Points:")
       for point in snowflake:
           print(point)
       rotated_snowflake = [rotate_point(p, (400, 300), rotation_angle) for p in snowflake]
       render_snowflake_with_plasma(rotated_snowflake, plasma_texture)
       rotation_angle = (rotation_angle + 1) % 360
       clock.tick(60)


Perhaps you might include your full script so that someone would not have to guess where things like glGenTextures() may have come from

glGenTextures() is a wrapper coming from OpenGL import. Full code would be too much. But I added the import-statements. Users who are able to answer this question, should therefore be familiar with Python and OpenGL statements.

Could you explain, since you asked a reopen, why you think the linked answer doesn't apply to you. And not just "because I wanted PYTHON" in all angry caps. That would be some technical argument to not "loose", but not a real answer. I mean, I do not, usually, code in C++ myself, but even if I knew nothing of C++, the first answer, « GL_POLYGON is only for convex polygon » seems crystal clear to me, and not specific to C++ at all.

The "angry caps" are just your imagination, because I didn’t phrase my question the way you alleged. A complete answer would include code to address the issue, which is why a PHYTHON-specific question has nothing to do with a C++ question, even if OpenGL is language-independent.
